# Prevent user from moving beyond boundaries R Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a map which shows Australia.

[image: A map of Australia]

What I want to do is to prevent the user going outside of this view. I know that I can pass providerTileOptions a minZoom and a bounds function, but this still enables the user to drag outside of this view (they'll just get blank grey).

How can I accomplish this?

Reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)



ui <- fluidPage(

    leafletOutput(
     "map",
     width = "100%",
     height = 500
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas,
                         options = providerTileOptions(
                           minZoom = 4,
                           bounds = list(
                            c(-7.275292, 57.04102),
                            c(-43.45292, 221.1328)
                           )
                         )
                         ) %>%
        setView(134.4727, -25.87899, zoom = 4)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with setMaxBounds()

```
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas,
                   options = providerTileOptions(
                     minZoom = 4,
                     bounds = list(
                       c(-7.275292, 57.04102),
                       c(-43.45292, 221.1328)
                     )
                   )
  ) %>%
  setView(134.4727, -25.87899, zoom = 4) %>%
  setMaxBounds(57.04102, -7.275292, 221.1328, -43.45292)
```